# How to define visibility of Kendo Grid command

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to hide Edit command for some records. There is columns.command.visible configuration option for that (according to documentation). So I tried this:

```
{
  command: [
    {
      name: "edit",
      visible: function(dataItem) {
        return false;
      },
```

I expected Edit command would be hidden for all records. But it's not. Looks like this option doesn't work at all.

Probably it could be related to version of Kendo I use: 2014.1.318
Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a dojo (http://dojo.telerik.com) ? It works here: http://dojo.telerik.com/aBaPU

Comment: Yes, it works there. Could it be related to old Kendo version: 2014.1.318 ?

Comment: I wasn't sure about the version, but if it works now then it was the problem probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was old Kendo version. I used 2014.1.318. After upgrading to 2017.1.118 it works fine.